# How to disable "USB Device not recognized" notifications?

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit, notification-area, device-manager

The notification says something like:

> "USB Device not recognized: One of the devices attached to this
>   computer has malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it."

and it's very annoying. It shows up even if I have no external USB devices connected.

In the "Device Manager" is listed as "Unknown device" inside the Universal Serial Bus controllers category. Disabling/uninstalling it doesn't make the notification go away. I don't even know what device this is, so I can disable it in the BIOS. Tried disabling some of them randomly but the thing still shows up.

Is there anything I can do to make it stop?

A screenshot of the unknown device properties after I uninstalled it and Windows reinstalled it automatically:
[image: Device manager]

Comment: What model of computer do you have, or is it custom built?  Also, what are the values of the "Hardware Ids" property on the "Details" tab of the device in Device Manager?

Comment: Hardware Ids property shows "USB\UNKNOWN". The computer is a Dell Latitude E5540

Answer (score 1):

Per this [thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/288112-usb-device-not-recognized-cannot-stop-error-message.html) you can go and disable the "Diagnostic Policy Service" to stop the notifications. You can do this by doing the following:

1. Open services.msc (get a run prompt and type "services.msc")
2. Find the Diagnostic Policy Service
3. Stop the service
4. If you want this to be persistent, set it's status to 'Disabled"

Comment: Nope, sorry. It still comes up. I set it to manual and now it's stopped and I get the notification :(